# Random ElementTree.ParseError when fetching Flickr data

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree, flickr

I am writing a script to pull selected metadata from my Flickr account for all photos therein. As the script is moving through the photosets, I get a (seemingly) random `ElementTree.ParseError`:

```
File "flickr-get.py", line 95, in <module>
    get_photoset_metadata(key)
  File "flickr-get.py", line 51, in get_photoset_metadata
    photo = flickr.photos_getInfo(photo_id=node.get('id'), api_key=mdah_api_key)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/flickrapi/__init__.py", line 337, in handler
    parse_format=args['format'], **args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/flickrapi/__init__.py", line 423, in __wrap_in_parser
    return parser(self, data)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/flickrapi/__init__.py", line 258, in parse_etree
    rsp = ElementTree.fromstring(rest_xml)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1301, in XML
    return parser.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1654, in close
self._raiseerror(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1506, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

I say random because this exception will occur at unpredictable points in photo processing.

It seems like if it were an absent value in the XML, or an encoding problem it would be predictable, so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it. I know I'm well under the calls-per-hour limit.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse
import flickrapi
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

mdah_api_key = 'something'
mdah_api_secret = 'something'

fileencoding = "iso-8859-1"

flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(mdah_api_key, mdah_api_secret)                      

# authorize user
(token, frob) = flickr.get_token_part_one(perms='write')                                                            
if not token: 
   raw_input('Press ENTER after you authorized this program')
flickr.get_token_part_two((token, frob))

photosets_dict = dict()                                                                                                                                         

f = open('flickr-data.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='export metadata for Flickr user by set (or all photos if no set specified)')

parser.add_argument('-u','--user', default='something', help='target Flickr user')
parser.add_argument('-p','--photoset', default='all', help='target photoset')
args = parser.parse_args()

def get_photoset_metadata(photoset):

    photoset_info_tree = ET.ElementTree(flickr.photosets_getInfo(api_key=mdah_api_key, photoset_id=photoset))       
    photoset_tree = ET.ElementTree(flickr.photosets_getPhotos(api_key=mdah_api_key, photoset_id=photoset))  

    photo_ids = []  
    data = []
    data_row = []

    for title in photoset_info_tree.iter('title'):
      set_title = title.text.decode(fileencoding)    

    # grab all photo ids in set
    for node in photoset_tree.iter('photo'):

      # get each photo
      photo = flickr.photos_getInfo(photo_id=node.get('id'), api_key=mdah_api_key)
      photo_tree = ET.ElementTree(photo)

      data_row.append(set_title)

      for title in photo_tree.iter('title'):
         data_row.append(title.text.decode(fileencoding))

      try:
         geodata = flickr.photos_geo_getLocation(photo_id=node.get('id'), api_key=mdah_api_key)
         geodata_tree = ET.ElementTree(geodata)

         for geonode in geodata_tree.iter('location'):            
            data_row.append(geonode.get('latitude').decode(fileencoding))
            data_row.append(geonode.get('longitude').decode(fileencoding))
            data_row.append(geonode.get('accuracy').decode(fileencoding))
         for geonode in geodata_tree.iter('country'):
            data_row.append(geonode.text.decode(fileencoding))         
         for geonode in geodata_tree.iter('region'):
            data_row.append(geonode.text.decode(fileencoding))
         for geonode in geodata_tree.iter('county'):
            data_row.append(geonode.text.decode(fileencoding))
         for geonode in geodata_tree.iter('locality'):
            data_row.append(geonode.text.decode(fileencoding))
         for geonode in geodata_tree.iter('neighbourhood'):
            data_row.append(geonode.text.decode(fileencoding))
      except Exception as e:
         e = True

      writer.writerow(data_row)
      print data_row     

      data_row = []

if args.photoset == 'all':
   photosets_tree = ET.ElementTree(flickr.photosets_getList(api_key=mdah_api_key, user_id=args.user))   

   # grab all photosets     
   for node in photosets_tree.iter('photoset'):
      photosets_dict[node.get('id')] = node[0].text

   # iterate over photosets dictionary
   for key, value in photosets_dict.items():
      print '-- Exporting metadata from ' + key + ', ' + value + ' --'
      get_photoset_metadata(key)
else:
   get_photoset_metadata(args.photoset)
```

This is the first few lines of a `flickr.photos.getInfo` XML return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rsp stat="ok">
  <photo id="8009597985" secret="something" server="8182" farm="9" dateuploaded="1348248234" isfavorite="0" license="7" safety_level="0" rotation="0" originalsecret="something" originalformat="png" views="97" media="photo">
    <owner nsid="77015680@N05" username="Mississippi Department of Archives and History" realname="" location="" iconserver="5324" iconfarm="6" path_alias="mississippi-dept-of-archives-and-history" />
    <title>Memphis Warehouse Company.</title>
```